# Unpublish workflow command disabled in Published (final state) in CE

Tags: content-editor, workflow

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 along with SXA 1.7.1
We have a workflow in place with these states:

```
1. Draft (initial state)
2. Approver Approval
3. Publisher Approval (it has Approve and Reject workflow command)
4. Published (Final State)
```

In Published state we have below:

```
1. Auto Publish (workflow action)
2. Un-Publish (workflow command)
```

Once a publisher approves, the item moves to the Published state and it gets published automatically.

In the Published state we have an Un-Publish workflow command to unpublish the item. The Un-Publish button is visible but disabled in the workflow section of the Review tab in the content editor.

When a publisher opens this item in the experience editor, the Un-Publish button is visible and enabled and working fine when they click on it.

Is there a way to enable this button in the Content Editor also?

Permissions are granted to the publisher role for the Un-Publish workflow command, but it still is disabled in CE:

```
1. Read
2. Workflow State Delete
3. Workflow State Write
4. Workflow Command Execute
```

Comment: Around v. 8.2, Sitecore changed the Workflow Panel so that, IIRC, 
some commands that used to be enabled from final states became disabled. We worked around it for a while by creating a customized version of Sitecore's Workflow Panel code, but ultimately we redesigned our Unpublish use case (which, like yours, used to be a workflow command from final state) as a non-Workflow ribbon button.

Comment: do you mean that it is not possible to enable custom command button in final state of workflow in content editor ?

Comment: "do you mean that it is not possible to enable custom command button in final state of workflow in content editor ?" Something like that, I don't remember the exact details. May have had something to do with items having to be in Edit mode to enable buttons, and a setting which creates a new version on entering Edit mode, which we didn't want.